# Total Solutions Amount

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we assume $Ax = 0$ only has ONE solution.

How many solutions will $(A^T)Ax$ = 0 have?

---

Will there be 1 solution? $A^TA = I_n$, the identity matrix. Hence there is only one possible vector that gives the solution?

Comment: What is $A$? An arbitrary matrix? Or a square one?

Comment: If $A^TAx=0$, then $x^TA^TAx=x^T0=0$. But $x^TA^TAx=(Ax)^T(Ax)=\|Ax\|$. If $\|Ax\|=0$, then $Ax=0$. Therefore, solutions of $A^TAx=0$, are solutions of $Ax=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is irrelevant.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Yes, you're right. Why don't you post your other comment as an answer?

Comment: @spiralstotheleft is my line of reasoning justified for ONE solution for ATAx=0 when Ax = 0 has one solution?

Comment: That is what I proved, but the argument of why that happens is required. What you wrote below the line is not correct. $A^TA$ doesn't have to be $I$.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
x^\top A^\top A x = y^\top y = y^2 = \lVert y \Vert_2^2 \ge 0
$$
with $y = Ax$.

The norm $\lVert y \rVert_2$ vanishes only for $y = 0$.

As $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution, we know
$x = 0 \iff y = 0$.

Which means the symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A^\top A$ is positive definite.

This means it can be diagonalized with positive eigenvalues only and thus 
$$
\det(A^\top A) = \prod \lambda_i \ne 0
$$
So $A^\top A$ is bijective, with only $0$ as solution to $A^\top A x = 0$.

In general $A^\top A$ might be different from the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If it has only One solution, then it must be $\mathbf 0$, hence $\boldsymbol A$ is invertible, hence so is $\boldsymbol A ^{\mathsf T} \boldsymbol A$. Therefore the solution is only $\mathbf 0$.